# Impossible to include PNotify with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, pnotify

So, I export `PNotify` from bower to the `js` folder. I use `requirejs` to include my libraries

**HTML**

```
<script data-main="assets/js/app" type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/lib/require.js"></script>
```

My architecture is like this :

```
js
--- app.js
--- lib
------ pnotify.core.js
------ pnotify.desktop.js
------ pnotify.buttons.js
------ pnotify.callbacks.js
------ pnotify.confirm.js
------ pnotify.history.js
------ pnotify.nonblock.js
------ pnotify.reference.js
------ jquery.js
------ ...
```

I add the primary module which is pnotify.core

**APP.JS**

```
requirejs.config({
    base: '/assets/js',
    paths: {
        'jQuery': 'lib/jquery.min',
        'underscore': 'lib/underscore-min',
        'Backbone': 'lib/backbone',
        'Modernizr' : 'lib/modernizr',
        'PNotify' : 'lib/pnotify.core',
        'LoginView' : 'views/login'
    },
    shim: {
        'jQuery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'Backbone': {
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'Modernizr': {
            exports: 'Modernizr'
        },
        'LoginView': {
            exports: 'LoginView'
        },
        'PNotify': {
            exports: 'PNotify'
        }
    }
});
```

PNotify is loaded in my page. Normally, PNotify works with requirejs : https://github.com/sciactive/pnotify#using-pnotify-with-requirejs

I don't know how can I import all modules, maybe concat these modules in one file pnotify.min.js?

Here, when I call the `PNotify` object under the `requirejs.config`

```
define(['jQuery', 'underscore', 'Backbone', 'Modernizr', 'LoginView', 'PNotify'], function ($, _, Backbone, Modernizr, LoginView, PNotify) {
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        new PNotify({
            title: 'Desktop Notice',
            text: 'If you\'ve given me permission, I\'ll appear as a desktop notification. If you haven\'t, I\'ll still appear as a regular PNotify notice.'
        });
    });
});
```

I have this error : `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the line "new PNotify"...

Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When they detect AMD/RequireJS, PNotify core defines the named module
>   "**pnotify**", and PNotify's modules each define names like
>   "pnotify.module". The following example shows the use of the nonblock
>   and desktop modules with RequireJS.

So my error is here

```
requirejs.config({
    base: '/assets/js',
    paths: {
        'jQuery': 'lib/jquery.min',
        'underscore': 'lib/underscore-min',
        'Backbone': 'lib/backbone',
        'Modernizr' : 'lib/modernizr',
        'PNotify' : 'lib/pnotify.core',
            ^_____ 'replace by pnotify'
        'LoginView' : 'views/login'
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Compile All the modules into one minified file.

These Settings work for me in Require.js

```
paths: {
   'pnotify': 'lib/pnotify.min',
   'pnotify.nonblock': 'lib/pnotify.min',
   'pnotify.desktop': 'lib/pnotify.min,
   'jquery' : 'lib/jquery'
}

define(['jquery', 'pnotify','pnotify.nonblock', 'pnotify.desktop', function($, pnotify){

     new PNotify({
        title: 'Desktop Notice',
        text: 'If you\'ve given me permission, I\'ll appear as a desktop notification. If you haven\'t, I\'ll still appear as a regular PNotify notice.',
        desktop: {
            desktop: true
        },
        nonblock: {
            nonblock: true
        }
    });
});
```